# jQuery scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are a bunch of links and tips on building a jQuery scroll, and I get them to work in JS Fiddle, but for some reason it doesn't work when I use it in Visual Studio. I have a separate file for jQuery v1.7.2 (I downloaded from the site), a javascript file called script.js that has this code in it for the scrolling on click:

```
 $('a').click(function () {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 3000);
     return false;
 });
```

I have a fixed navigation that when you click on the links the page scrolls behind the navigation. And the actual links work as I'm using anchor tags, but it isn't easing in and easing out. When you use something similar in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/ it works, but when I try to use it in my code it doesn't. Here is my code:

```
      <div class="navigation">
      <ul id="navmenu">
          <li id="mainlogo"></li>
      </ul>
         <div class="mainnav">
              <ul id="actualnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#topbar" rel="">Home &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#aboutushome" rel="">About Us &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#productshome" rel="">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="resumatics">powered by resumatics</span>
                    </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
  </div>
```

I have 2 id's so far that when you click on the "Home" link it goes to the top of the page where I placed this line of code for an anchor:

```
    <div class="topbar" id="topbar"></div>
```

Then about another page down I placed another anchor for the 2nd link, the "About Us" link here:

```
     <div class="middlebar1" id="aboutushome"></div>
```

So the links do work as the page goes straight from one point to another, but the easing down the page and up the page doesn't work, its' just a straight shot. What am I missing here?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli ya, i always forget about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you ahave actually included the files (*jquery and your own script*) in the page you are testing..

Then call your code after the DOM is ready (*otherwise the code will not find the links to attach the handlers, since it has not been read from the file..*)

So

```
$(function(){ //this is the way to run your code at the DOM Ready event

    $('a').click(function () {
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
         }, 3000);
         return false;
     });

});
```

Comment: well that did it, but I still don't understand how it works in jsfiddle without the $(function(){} start? Thanks btw!

Comment: @colasus, If you look at the left panel on jsfiddle, under ***Frameworks & Extensions*** the second `select` box specifies when to execute your code. By default it is set to `onLoad` which is after `DOM ready` so the page (*even images*) have loaded before running your script.. If you set it to ***No-wrap, in head*** it will not work.